# Как разделить на блоки левое меню в битриксе?

Tags: php, javascript, html, битрикс

Добрый день, всем! Помогите мне очень нужно решить данную задачу, знаний в битриксе, как и в php у меня не много. Есть сайт на 1С-Битрикс Управление сайтом. Ссылку на сайт привести не могу. На сайте есть левое вертикальное меню, такого же вида как на фото:

[image: Левое вертикальное меню]

Необходимо переделать левое вертикальное меню, а именно разделить (разбить данное меню) на блоки также как это выглядит на фотке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом родительские пункты меню, слова Химчистка, Уборка не должны быть ссылками, а должны быть текстовыми заголовками, не активными пунктами меню, т.е. на них нельзя нажать и они никуда не должны вести. 
Остальные пункты меню при этом должны быть рабочими, ссылки на страницы при этом не должны измениться. 
Меню не должно быть раскрывающемся выпадающим списком, оно должно быть всегда открытым на всех страницах сайта.
Как это можно реализовать? Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Привожу пример кода компонента левого вертикального меню на PHP:

```html
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

<?if (!empty($arResult)):?>

<?
global $APPLICATION;
$dir = $APPLICATION->GetCurDir();
?>

<ul class="left_menu_ul">

<?
$previousLevel = 0;
foreach($arResult as $arItem):?>

 <?if ($previousLevel && $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] < $previousLevel):?>
  <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel - $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"]));?>
 <?endif?>

 <?if ($arItem["IS_PARENT"]):?>
 
  <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
   <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"] && $dir==$arItem["LINK"]) {?>
                <li class="selected parent"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="selected"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
     <ul class="selected">
           <?}else if ($arItem["SELECTED"]) {?>
             <li class="parent"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
     <ul class="selected">
            <?}else{?>
             <li class="parent"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
     <ul>
           <?}?>
  <?else:?>
   <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"] && $dir==$arItem["LINK"]) {?>
                <li class="selected parent"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="selected"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
     <ul class="selected">
           <?}else if ($arItem["SELECTED"]) {?>
             <li class="parent"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
     <ul class="selected">
            <?}else{?>
             <li class="parent"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
     <ul>
            <?}?>
  <?endif?>

 <?else:?>

  <?if ($arItem["PERMISSION"] > "D"):?>
  
   <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
    <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"] && $dir==$arItem["LINK"]) {?>
     <li class="selected"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="selected"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
                <?}else if ($arItem["SELECTED"]) {?>
                 <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
                <?}else{?>
                 <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
               <?}?>
   <?else:?>
    <?if ($arItem["SELECTED"] && $dir==$arItem["LINK"]) {?>
     <li class="selected"><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" class="selected"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
                <?}else if ($arItem["SELECTED"]) {?>
                 <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
                <?}else{?>
                 <li><a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
                <?}?>
   <?endif?>

  <?else:?>

   <?if ($arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"] == 1):?>
    <li class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>selected<?endif?>"><a href="" class="<?if ($arItem["SELECTED"]):?>selected<?endif?>" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?else:?>
    <li><a href="" class="denied" title="<?=GetMessage("MENU_ITEM_ACCESS_DENIED")?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a></li>
   <?endif?>

  <?endif?>

 <?endif?>

 <?$previousLevel = $arItem["DEPTH_LEVEL"];?>

<?endforeach?>

<?if ($previousLevel > 1)://close last item tags?>
 <?=str_repeat("</ul></li>", ($previousLevel-1) );?>
<?endif?>

</ul>
<div class="menu-clear-left"></div>
<?endif?>
```

Сделал print_r($arItem). На выходе получил:

```html
ARRAY ( 
[TEXT] => ХИМЧИСТКА КОВРОВ 
[LINK] => /HIMCHISTKA-KOVROV/ 
[SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X 
[ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 0 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( 
[TEXT] => ХИМЧИСТКА МАТРАСА [LINK] => /HIMCHISTKA-MATRASA/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 1 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 
1 [IS_PARENT] => ) 
ARRAY ( [TEXT] => ЧИСТКА КОВРОЛИНА [LINK] => /HIMCHISTKA-KOVROLINA/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 2 [PARAMS] 
=> ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => ХИМЧИСТКА КОВРОВ С ВЫВОЗОМ [LINK] => /HIMCHISTKA-KOVROV-S-VYVOZOM/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( 
) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 3 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => ХИМЧИСТКА МЯГКОЙ МЕБЕЛИ [LINK] => /HIMCHISTKA-MJAGKOJ-MEBELI/ [SELECTED] => 
[PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 4 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => ХИМЧИСТКА ДИВАНОВ [LINK] => 
/HIMCHISTKA-DIVANOV/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 5 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => 
УБОРКА КВАРТИР [LINK] => /UBORKA-KVARTIR/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 6 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => 
) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => УБОРКА КОТТЕДЖЕЙ [LINK] => /UBORKA-KOTTEDZHEJ/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 7 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) 
[DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => УБОРКА ОФИСОВ [LINK] => /UBORKA-OFISOV/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 8 
[PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => УБОРКА КВАРТИР ПОСЛЕ РЕМОНТА [LINK] => /UBORKA-POSLE-REMONTA/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => 
ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 9 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => МОЙКА ОКОН [LINK] => /MOJKA-OKON/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X 
[ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 10 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => УДАЛЕНИЕ ЗАПАХОВ [LINK] => /UDALENIE-ZAPAHOV/ 
[SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 11 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => ОБОРУДОВАНИЕ [LINK] 
=> /OBORUDOVANIE/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 12 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => 
МОЮЩИЕ СРЕДСТВА [LINK] => /HIMICHESKIE-SREDSTVA/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 13 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 
[IS_PARENT] => ) ARRAY ( [TEXT] => ТЕРРИТОРИЯ ОБСЛУЖИВАНИЯ [LINK] => /TERRITORIJA-OBSLUZHIVANIJA/ [SELECTED] => [PERMISSION] => X [ADDITIONAL_LINKS] => ARRAY ( ) [ITEM_TYPE] => D [ITEM_INDEX] => 
14 [PARAMS] => ARRAY ( ) [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1 [IS_PARENT] => )
```

Что в нем нужно изменить, чтобы реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: Сделайте print_r($arItem); внутри цикла, посмотрите из чего состоит он и выложите сюда. И стили css кода не нужны, уберите их.

Comment: Добавьте его в вопрос и добавьте все массивы которые срендерились, а не только последний кусок.
Я без понятий как работает битрикс, но предполагал, что раз у вас задача разделить список, то возможно страницы и так поделены на категории. Но видно, что `[IS_PARENT]` пуст, а значит они не вложены в категории, т.е. вам сначала надо эти страницы поделить на категории, а потом уже выводить их раздельно.

Comment: DimenSi, а как мне страницы вложить в категории. Дело в том, что если я создам папку, которая будет являться категорией, а в ней папку, которая будет являться страницей, это не решит задачу, то есть у меня изменяться ссылки на страницы, а ссылки на страницы не должны меняться.

Comment: Я предлагаю вам подумать или погуглить решения. Я не специалист битрикс, я пытался вам подсказать логику действий.

Comment: Подумать я подумаю, а что касается погуглить я уже гуглил, но никакого решения по данному вопросу пока не смог найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианта решения тут на самом деле несколько:

1) Разбить меню на несколько типов. Первый тип это категории, второй подкатегории

2) Сделать по отдельному типу меню для каждой категории.

3) Дополнительным параметром (при редактировании меню в расширенном режиме в административной части) указывать категорию для каждого пункта и в шаблоне по ней группировать

Comment: Mihanik71, 1)  У меня вроде как уже есть несколько типов меню leftmenu1 (категории) и leftmenu2 (подкатегории), или это не то? Если не то, где тогда это делается в битриксе управление сайтом, т.е. где указывается тип категории и подкатегории, как сделать чтобы в данном случае не нужно было указывать ссылки категориям? 2) Что значит сделать по отдельному типу где это можно указать и какой тип меню должен быть? 3) Какой параметр нужно указывать и для каких пунктов меню, для всех? Как в шаблоне потом группировать по этому параметру? Можете написать, как сделать 1 и 3 вариант?